# How to change HTML custom attribute value by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have this :

```
<div id="e2" 
    class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger active"
    role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="45">
```

And I want to change the data-transitiongoal value at run-time.

This doesn't work for me:

```
document.getElementById("e2").setAttribute("data-transitiongoal", "10");
```

Comment: Are you running the code after the document has loaded? E.g. using *window.onload* or script at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you told that you want to change at run time and you already tried one solution which will change it at loading itself, I suggest you the things.
Read this to understand and then only copy the below code.

1. set a `Timeout function` which change the data and inside the function, clear the `Timeout` in order to avoid repetitive execution.
2. set the duration in milliseconds such that after how much time you want to make the change. 2000 -> 2 seconds. 0 -> immediate ( seconds * 1000).

You can check the console and duration to detect when and where the change appeared.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('e2')); // log actual element -> 45
var SIT=window.setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("e2").setAttribute("data-transitiongoal", "10");
  console.log(document.getElementById('e2'));
  window.clearTimeout(SIT);
},2000); // change duration
// log changed element -> 10
```

```html
<div id="e2" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger active" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="45">Something</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are doing something else wrong because `setAttribute()` works. Could you post some more code? See for yourself:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("e2");

console.log(elem.getAttribute("data-transitiongoal"));
elem.setAttribute("data-transitiongoal", 10);
console.log(elem.getAttribute("data-transitiongoal"));
```

```html
<div id="e2" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger active" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="45">
```